# Is there a way to draw a SVG in PDFTron?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, pdftron

Previously, I tried to use an Annotation.StampAnnotation to create a custom annotation while using a SVG as the base image, however I discovered that the user cannot change or set the colour of a StampAnnotation. Hence, I am now using an Annotation.MarkupAnnotation.

As of right now, I am having trouble drawing the inline SVG (string) on the CanvasRenderingContext2D using drawImage(). I saw some code on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-draw-an-SVG-file-on-an-HTML5-canvas), and I tested it in a Javascript sandbox, and it seems to work. However, when I implemented it with PDFTron, it only draws an empty box on the PDF.

Here's my code:

```
createCustomAnnotation: function (Annotations, annotManager, subject, inlineSVGString) {

        const CustomAnnotation = function () {
            Annotations.MarkupAnnotation.call(this);
            this.Subject = subject;
        }

        CustomAnnotation.prototype = new Annotations.MarkupAnnotation();

        CustomAnnotation.prototype.draw = function (ctx, pageMatrix) {
            this.setStyles(ctx, pageMatrix);

            var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
            var img = new Image();
            var svg = new Blob([inlineSVGString], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
            var x = this.X;
            var y = this.Y;
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 30, 30);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
            img.src = url;

        }

        return CustomAnnotation;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there

Looks like the sample from Tutorials Point has a syntax error and it only draws an empty box, if you try this sample it draws the text correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>SVG file on HTML Canvas </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:2px solid green;" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
      <script>
         var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
         var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">' +
            '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
               '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:50px">' +
                  'Simply Easy ' +
                  '<span style="color:blue;">' +
                  'Learning</span>' +
               '</div>' +
            '</foreignObject>' +
         '</svg>';
         var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
         var img1 = new Image();
         var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
         var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
         img1.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 25, 70);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
         }
         img1.src = url;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sardor, thanks for your comment! Would you mind pointing out the syntax error in TutorialsPoint's sample? Because I tested TutorialsPoint's code in a separate sandbox, and it works